# Can't see existing product attributes in backend

Tags: product, module, magento-1

There's an attribute which has been assigend to an attribute set and there's a product using that set.

I have successfully created attributes and added them to attribute sets. However, when I create a new product, those attributes aren't visible in the backend. Also, I can set and retrieve data programmatically, but I cannot see the attributes in the backend.

I have cleared all caches and reindexed everything

***EDIT*** This is what I'm doing at the moment to create the attribute

```
            /* @var $attributeModel Mage_Catalog_Model_Entity_Attribute */
            $attributeModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
            $attributeModel->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);
            $attributeModel->setAttributeCode($propName);
            $attributeModel->setBackendType('varchar');
            $attributeModel->setName($propName);
            $attributeModel->setFrontendLabel($propDesc);

            $attributeModel->save();
```

Comment: Did you set the source model to database? Or created the attribute definition in XML?

Comment: I used the attribute model and created the attributed programmatically. Will post the code later (5 hours or so)

Comment: It was probably just incorrectly created. Let's see the code!

Comment: @musicliftsme there you go, see my edit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be missing the `frontend_input` value. Look up the table `eav_attribute` and see which fields you're missing. One sure way to know which values are required for an attribute you'd like to create programmatically is to create one from the admin and examine the record in `eav_attribute`.

```
$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
    ->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId)
    ->setAttributeCode($propName)
    ->setBackendType('varchar')
    ->setName($propName)
    ->setFrontendLabel($propDesc)
    ->setFrontendInput('multiselect')   // Or could be 'text', 'select', etc.
    ->setBackendModel(...) // not necessarily required 
    ->save();
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution. I have no idea what made me ommit this because I actually had it earlier and thought it was unnecessary

Comment: This still isn't correct. You won't find your attribute via Eav/Attribute collection, which is used in a few places. I've bookmarked your question to remind me when I'm behind something else than a smartphone ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you create an attribute programmatically, the default source model is Xml. Which means a definition of the attribute is supposed to exist in your module config.

You have to set the source model to table (don't have the exact string available at the moment, but look into `Mage/Eav` source models), so that the attribute definition is looked up from there.

EDIT:

As posted above, you're missing the frontendInput, but also the source model:

```
/* @var $attributeModel Mage_Catalog_Model_Entity_Attribute */
$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
$attributeModel->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);
$attributeModel->setAttributeCode($propName);
$attributeModel->setBackendType('varchar');
$attributeModel->setName($propName);
$attributeModel->setFrontendLabel($propDesc);
$attributeModel->setFrontendInput('select');
$attributeModel->setSourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table');

$attributeModel->save();
```

Now, I'm being a bit mean :) but it's for educational purposes!

The method `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract::usesSource` defines when a source model is needed:

```
    return $this->getFrontendInput() === 'select' || $this->getFrontendInput() === 'multiselect'
        || $this->getData('source_model') != '';
```

So, the answer provided above, you really need a source model! This is because selects and multi-selects are compound fields, so the source model needs to take care of fetching the selected value of the compound to a single entity to be referenced in the attribute field. This also means, that in the "table" source model, that is used and prepared for you in this case, you cannot use a varchar attribute. The backend model needs to be an integer as it will reference the autoincrement id of the ManyToMany relation table `eav_attribute_option_value`.

Hope this helps you understand things better.

Comment: please check out my edit, I believe I am already doing what you're asking me to